# Redirect to .pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, redirect

On browsing local.com/test/document, I want to redirect to local.com/document/demo.pdf

It is getting redirected properly. i.e demo.pdf file is getting downloaded. But browser Url is not getting changed.

I am using following lines of code for redirection:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("local.com/document/demo.pdf", false);
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Is this the correct behavior as we are redirecting to file? or is there a way where file can be downloaded and also browser url gets changed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Response.Redirect(),because the it's a function and can do one task at a time.
    You can use

```
<a href="http://xyz.pdf" **target="_self"**>Click Me</a>
Change the target _blank,it will redirect to a new tab.
```

You can also go with

```
        <iframe src="xyz.pdf"></iframe>
```